# Is it possible to add vertical lines to tables produced with R knitr::kable in pdf?

Tags: r, knitr, vertical-alignment, kable

I want to produce a table with `knitr::kable` with vertical lines on the borders and between certain columns. Is there a way to do it?
My output document is pdf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Not too much clear, but maybe this could help:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
dt %>% 
kable() %>%
# here you can add the vertical line, in my example, for all the columns
column_spec (1:7,border_left = T, border_right = T) %>%
kable_styling()
```

[image]

And if you need to save it as `.pdf`:

```
save_kable(k, "k.pdf")
```

With `k` as the result of the code above.

Comment: Thank you. Could the lines be extended to the column names and to a header added above with `add_header_above` and `kable_styling(latex_options =c("repeat_header"))`?

Comment: In my case, I got the columns also between column lines but discontinued, as separated lines.

Comment: You're welcome. Unluckily it seems not possible, but maybe my knowledge about this package is poor. Maybe you'll get a better answer waiting.

Comment: If you're willing to try a different package, `huxtable` (mine) will do this.

Comment: @dash2 that's great, you should add an answer with your solution using your package.

Answer (score 2):

Answer using huxtable:

```
library(huxtable)
library(dplyr)

as_hux(mtcars[1:5, 1:6], add_colnames = TRUE) %>%
      set_right_border(2:5, everywhere, 0.4) %>%
      set_bottom_border(1, everywhere, 0.4)
```

You can then save it to PDF with `quick_pdf()`, or print it within a rmarkdown document.