# How to add vertical lines to a manually created table in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627689/is-it-possible-to-add-vertical-lines-to-tables-produced-with-r-knitrkable-in-p) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66234917/can-i-add-lines-that-will-visually-delineate-groups-of-columns-with-kableextra). However, all the solutions rely mainly on using the `kableExtra` package to create a table. I am trying to create a table manually in R Markdown, without using any additional packages.

The reason I am doing it manually is because some of my table entries require special characters (or contain LaTex commands, such as `\url{some url}`) or contain links to external websites. As a result, I'm not sure if I can use the `kableExtra` package (or similar).

However, I am trying to manually replicate how a `kableExtra` table looks, specifically I'm trying to add vertical lines between each column and for it to be consistent between a knitted HTML and pdf file.

For example, using the code below, I am creating a table manually and by using `kableExtra`. In the manually created table I am including links to wikipedia (which Im not sure if I can do using `kableExtra`). However, as mentioned above, in my actual table I need to include LaTex commands (which I omit here for simplicity). The first image is a knitted HTML and the second image is a knitted pdf.

1: Manually created table:

```
| Make                                                       | mpg     | cyl  |  disp |
|:-----------------------------------------------------------|:--------|:-----|:------|
| [Mazda RX4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Luce)      | 21.0    | 6    |  160  |
| [Mazda RX4 Wag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Luce)  | 21.0    | 6    |  160  |
| [Datsun 710](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Violet)  | 22.8    | 4    |  108  |
```

2: kableExtra created table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

dt <- mtcars[1:3, 1:3]
dt %>% 
tibble::rownames_to_column("Make") %>%
knitr::kable() %>%
kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "bordered")
```

This is how the above code knits to HTML:
[image: HTML tables]

And this is how the above code knits to pdf:

[image: pdf tables]

As can be seen, when using `kableExtra`, there are vertical lines separating each column. I was wondering if it is possible to replicate this via the manual method?

Answer (score 0):

You can have urls and special characters in `kableExtra`; if you share what type of special characters you have in mind, we can definitely render those as well. There are questions about how to render special characters in `kable` already.

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(stringr)

read.table(text = " Make                                     mpg     cyl    disp 
 [Mazda_RX4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Luce)       21.0     6      160  
 [Mazda_RX4_Wag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazda_Luce)   21.0     6      160  
 [Datsun_710](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Violet)   22.8     4      108", 
           header = T) -> df1

df1 %>% 
  mutate(make_link = str_match_all(Make, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))"),
         make_text = str_match_all(Make, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])"),
         Make = cell_spec(make_text, "html", link = make_link)) %>%
  select(-c(make_link, make_text)) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = FALSE, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("bordered"))
```

[image]

Comment: This works for HTML but it doesn't format correctly for me when knitting to pdf. I had to add `always_allow_html: true` to the YAML to the front-matter of my document to allow it to knit the pdf. I was getting an error otherwise

Comment: @Electrino yup, sorry forgot to mention that. I was just knitting a standalone table. For the document, you do need that. Thanks for pointing it out.